# Cannot see my website from my network

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

I have a website hosted on my Raspberry Pi, in my home. I can access it with no problems from wifi networks other than my own. However, on my home wifi, if I type the address (damson.dnsdynamic.com) into Firefox:

"The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading"

Or into Chrome:

"Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Why is this? Why does it work fine everywhere except this network?

Thank you for your time

Comment: you must use local ip adress while at home.

Comment: Is this on-topic for programming?

Comment: Thank you EL3PHANTEN! And sorry if this is off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use local ip adress while on local network.
You could use a proxy server if you want to test the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Some routers cannot handle their Internet facing IP being accessed from inside the LAN.

You should either use a LAN IP address or upgrade your router.